# Filter tweets by user description

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, twitter-streaming-api

Hello I need to filter all the tweets whose user description matches a specific phrase (say, actor) . I am able to filter all the tweets which match the phrase but cannot filter only those in which user description has the phrase. Any ideas how to get this done ?

I am using the Twitter streaming api. This is what my code looks like till now ..

```
var Twit = require ('twit')


var Twits = new Twit ({
    consumer_key :          '....',
    consumer_secret:        '....', 
    access_token:           '....', 
    access_token_secret:    '....', 
    timeout_ms : 60*1000 ,
})

var stream = Twits.stream('statuses/filter' , { track : 'actor', language : 'en' })

 //var stream = Twits.stream('statuses/firehose')

var array = [];
stream.on( 'tweet', function (tweet) {

console.log (array)
})
```

Thanks .

Comment: Not possible to filter `statuses` by user description;

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 do you know any alternatives which I should look into? Thanks !!

Comment: Fetch all tweets then loop them and check `user.description` if it matches your requirement then use tweet else skip it;